# Flash Builder AS3 How to Show Tips for Unused Variables and Functions?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, editor, flash-builder, flash-builder4.5

I am used to FDT, and I really liked how if you declared a field variable (class variable) but did not use it in the class, it would give you a warning.

At my new workplace, though, it is Flash Builder exclusively. I'm not too unhappy because Flash Builder has some neat things of it's own.

Sometimes though I find that when I am in the zone focusing on getting the algorithm down right, I tend to get crazy with the ctrl+1. In the end, I have something that works with no bugs, but I know there is a lot of "unused" code.

FDT was a great help in trimming the fat, but in Flash Builder I find myself either deleting critical parts, or not deleting something I don't need because I think it's a critical part.

Note: I am also open to buying sourcemate if it can do this. I had the trial, but only really used it for when Flash Builder doesn't feel like generating a handler function.

Answer (score 0):

you're probably using Flash Builder 4.6 or below, FB 4.7 does that and has some even more neat features, unless you're a flex dev and used to the visual Design mode in FB which got removed in 4.7

Comment: I am using 4.5 Can I still use FlexPMD?

Answer (score 0):

If you using a FB4.7 below version, Use a [FlexPMD](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexpmd/home/Home/) plugin

```
FlexPMD is a tool that helps to improve code quality by auditing any AS3/Flex source directory and detecting common bad practices, such as:

* Unused code (functions, variables, constants, etc.)
* Inefficient code (misuse of dynamic filters, heavy constructors, etc.)
* Over-complex code (nested loops, too many conditionals, etc.)
* Over-long code (classes, methods, etc.)
* Incorrect use of the Flex component lifecycle (commitProperties, etc.)
```

Comment: I am using 4.5 I don't see a download for Flash Builder. Should I use the Eclipse one?

Comment: See a this article: http://zoltanb.co.uk/how-to-install-flexpmd-in-flex-builder-4-5/

Answer (score 0):

Actually I recently upgraded from 4.5 to 4.7 The new version has all of these features you are talking about. It is great! I am not sure if there is something you can install into 4.5 that it will do these things with the the extra warnings, but it really helps. hopefully someone else will post a way for you to be able to get it at work without having to convince your boss to buy 4.7